# How to solve conditional expectation time series process

Tags: economics, time-series

The following is a time series process:

$y_t = _0 + _1e_t + _2e_{t-1} + _3e_{t-2}$, where all the  are parameters, e is white noise, and t is the time index.

What is the result of taking the expectation of $y_t$ conditional on the information set available up and through period t-1?

So set up the equation but I'm not sure how to solve it after this. I used $Ω_{t-1}$ to represent the information set through period t-1.

$(y_t|Ω_{t-1}) = (_0 + _1_ + _2_{−1} + _3_{-2}|Ω)$

Comment: It seems like you need to define your variables more mathematically.

Comment: Agreed with 6005, I am not sure what $\Omega$ represents. But it seems the answer should be E($y_{t}$|$\Omega$)=$\beta_{0}$. Since the white noise elements all have expectation of zero.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Ω represents the informational set. I guessing $E(y_t|Ω)=β_0$ becuase the mean of white noise equals 0. If this is true how do you show the steps?